# Using paired t test if data is not normally distributed but the data set is large

Tags: t-test, normality-assumption

I need to test some before and after data, to see if there is a significant shift (n = 114) but the data differences are not normally distributed (or, at least, a histogram would seem to indicate that). Can I use a paired t-test?

Comment: 114 is not *that* large.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about a non-parametric test such as the [Mann-Wilcoxon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U)? You could test the before and after distribution to see if the average value has shifted significantly in one direction or the other.

#### Edit

@Scortchi is correct in that in your specific case, the [Wilcoxon signed rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) test would be a more appropriate non-parametric test.

Comment: Yes, I have considered using the Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test, but without a data analysis package like SPSS that is very tedious. I am hoping to use t tests as they are easy to complete using an Excel formula

Comment: If you have `R` it is easy. The [coin](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coin/index.html) package for R has a lot of non-parametric tests with both exact and asymptotic power calculations. I've done MWW tests in Excel; it isn't that difficult using RANK. If you have ties, you'll have to use some IF statements.

Comment: @Avraham: Note they're *paired* observations: you'd want the [Wilcoxon signed-rank test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) to test the null hypothesis that the mean difference within *each pair* is zero. And the OP might want to consider relying on the central limit theorem to justify the $t$-test approximately - it's quite a large sample size.

Comment: @Scortchi Yup; I should have been more precise in the specific non-parametric test. Personally when I use them, it is in the context of demonstrating changes in claim severity/frequency or aggregate loss distributions to indicate if prior experience for a given insurer may no longer be so credible vis-a-vis reinsurance pricing. As such, I'm not dealing with paired observations. Also, while the sample size may make the $t$ test still OK, the OP says the data does not look normal, and if e.g. there is heavy skew, the t wouldn't work so well, but non-parametric tests would still be appropriate.