Paired t test and CLT: What is supposed to be normally distributed?
I often read that the assumption of a paired t test is "that the data is normally distributed". And that the CLT will rescue you, if that is not the case when your sample size is large enough.

What data are we talking about? 1. The two samples? 2. Their difference? 3. Or the distribution of the mean of the difference?

I can see how the CLT has an influence on the normality of 3., but for 1. and 2., it does not apply, right?



Many similar Qs, probably a dup: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/495848/paired-t-test-check-normality-with-residuals-or-paired-differences-or-both, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15940/can-i-use-a-paired-t-test-when-the-samples-are-normally-distributed-but-their-di, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/360459/paired-sample-t-test-normality-violation, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69825/using-paired-t-test-if-data-is-not-normally-distributed-but-the-data-set-is-larg, ...

... https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229491/is-there-a-difference-between-a-paired-two-sample-t-test-and-one-sample-t-test-o, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/392098/trying-to-do-a-paired-t-test-but-one-variable-is-not-normally-distributed-log-t,

@kjetilbhalvorsen I just went trough these and non of them even mention the CLT??

All you really care about is the distribution of the test statistic, so some transformation of the mean of the differences. However, we do not have immediate access to the distribution of the test statistic (we could investigate it with, say, a bootstrap approach). Consequently, if we want to check assumptions, we want to look at something to which we have immediate access: the data. If the data are Gaussian, then we have a finite-sample guarantee about the test statistic being Gaussian, as required by the test. The rationale behind the CLT argument is that, if the data have a decent distribution, then the test statistic will be close to Gaussian, and the test will work about as it is meant to work, with larger deviations from the Gaussian ideal requiring larger sample sizes for this approximation to hold.
Worth noting is that an enormous sample size may be required for the asymptotic argument to “kick in” as it is, after all, related to a limit theorem that makes no finite-sample guarantees. Consequently, that practitioners often make assumptions like $30=\infty$ because the CLT will save us beyond a sample size of $30$ is not necessarily accurate, perhaps even grossly inaccurate. Likewise, you might not need to get close to $30$ for near-convergence to happen.
As far as what data you would investigate, the paired t-test is a one-sample t-test in disguise! The test does not consider the original paired data beyond taking the differences. Consequently, we would look at the differences being run through the one-sample t-test, not the original two distributions, which can be wildly non-Gaussian while having Gaussian differences that are fine for the paired test.
(I’ve glossed over some technical details that strike me as inappropriate for an answer to a question that seems to come from an introduction to statistics. In particular, the central limit theorem concerns convergence to a Gaussian distribution, yet the distribution in a t-test is the t-distribution. Also, the central limit theorem uses a known population variance, not an estimated sample variance. Readers may be interested in exploring these deeper ideas through Slutsky’s theorem and what I have heard referred to as the “converging together” lemma.)

Thanks What do you mean by
"The rationale behind the CLT argument is that, if the data are close to Gaussian, then the test statistic will be close to Gaussian, too, and the test will work about as it is meant to work, with larger deviations from the Gaussian ideal requiring larger sample sizes for this approximation to hold."
I do not think that is the rational of the CLT argument. I thought it goes:
data not normal => mean not normal... but for large sample sizes mean ->normal bc of CLT

That’s exactly what the argument is. The amazing part of the CLT is that the data can be wildly non-normal, yet the mean (at least a transformation of the mean used in the test) is close to normal, exactly normal “in” the limit. @PascalIv

ah ok, because you say "CLT argument is that, if the data are close to Gaussian, then the test statistic will be close to Gaussian,"
which talks about normality of the data, which does not matter for the CLT argument right? :)

Unless your sample size is infinity, you don’t care what happens “in” the limit. You care about what happens for your finite sample size. @PascalIv

I am not the one invoking CLT, it's everyone online :D But the CLT also proofs a certain rate of convergence, so it is not only a statement about the limit...?

@PascalIv There are theorems and proofs about rate of convergence, yes.

the paired t-test is a one-sample t-test in disguise! Nice! It never occurred to me. In fact the R code for t.test has if (paired) {x <- x-y; y <- NULL}

@PascalIv The CLT may help with the order of the rate of convergence, but not where it starts, so for any given sample size, it is possible to find a distribution for the difference (with finite variance) where the sample mean does not have a distribution close to a normal distribution.

The rationale behind the CLT argument is that, if the data are close to Gaussian, then the test statistic will be close to Gaussian. Do you need CLT for this? You need it for what follows afterwards. Maybe a small rephrasing could clarify this.

A really good example of a pathological dataset for this demo is a Cauchy distribution, formed by the ratio of two unit normals. Consider the following – even if you make n1=n2 very large, you'll never really get a t-distribution...library(boot); n1 <- 30; n2 <- 30; t_stat <- replicate(1000, {sample1 <- rnorm(n1) / rnorm(n1); sample2 <- rnorm(n2) / rnorm(n2); t.test(sample1, sample2)$statistic }); hist(t_stat, breaks=50, freq=FALSE, xlab="t", main="Sample t vs. Analytic t"); curve(dt(x, df=n1 + n2 - 2), col="red", add=TRUE) [Compare by removing /rnorm(n1) and  /rnorm(n1) ]!

@Landak Does this imply that without testing normality, one can never use a t test? Why do people use t tests?

@PascalIv That’s really a separate question, possibly a duplicate of an existing question with a good answer, one that is really quite deep.
